# Submit the form return the initialization of the object instead of null mvc C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

```
[HttpPost]    
public async Task<ActionResult> Create(BookingViewModel bookingview, BookingDetailsViewModel bookingdetails)
```

I am having a problem that when I submit the form I am expecting that the `bookingdetails` is null if I didn't show its `PartialView` related to it

```
@if (Model.StepNumber == (int)Booking_Steps.BookingDetails)
 {
   @Html.Partial("_Booking_Details", Model.BookingDetails)
 }
```

but instead it initialize the object. How to make it return null? because that's make the `ModelState` not valid.

Comment: The `DefaultModelBinder` will initialize all parameters in your method to their default value if no values are provided for them.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the model binder initializes objects to check their ModelState, although I could be mistaken.

A quick fix you could do is add a hidden field in the if block and check it in your action.

```
@if (Model.StepNumber == (int)Booking_Steps.BookingDetails)
{
  <input type="hidden" name="partialRenderedFlag" value="true" />
  @Html.Partial("_Booking_Details", Model.BookingDetails)
}
```

Controller action:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Create(BookingViewModel bookingview, BookingDetailsViewModel bookingdetails, bool partialRenderedFlag = false)
{
  if (partialRenderedFlag)
    // you know you rendered partial
}
```